# android township name from GPS location

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I'm trying to get township name/title of current geolocation. Unfortunately, `List<Address>` of andriod cannot support township name/title even I can see township name/title in Google maps. That's why please let me know how can I get township name from android `List<Address>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what i am doing:

```
ArrayList<Address> addresses = null;
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
try {
      addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) gCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 5);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
       Log.d("Adressline:",addresses.get(i).getAddressLine(0));
}
```

One of the adressline should give you the township name.

Comment: I've already tried like about coding but cannot get township name.

Comment: Have you tried 
getSubLocality() or getSubAdminArea()?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Google GeoCode API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Specifically:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=LAT,-LON